# How to draw a dashed svg path using anime.js?

Tags: css, animation, svg, anime.js

I know about ways using the second path that overlaps the first, but this method does not work for me, since gradient is used for the background.

When I try to draw a dashed line using this example https://animejs.com/documentation/#lineDrawing then nothing works for me, are there any ways to solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 900 228' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path d='M20 0 L 880 0 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20 L 900 208 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, 20 L 20 228 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, -20 L 0 15' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='1.6' stroke-dasharray='5' /></svg>"
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  width: 900px;
  height: 228px;
}
```

JS:

```
anime({
  targets: 'path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 3000,
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

example with anime.js: https://codepen.io/n4ks/pen/vYXxboa

In both cases, the behavior is not what is expected. I need to draw a dashed line from point A to point B (from beginning to end)

**Solution**

If anyone has encountered the same problem I will leave this demo here, many thanks to Paul LeBeau for the help: https://codepen.io/n4ks/pen/ExmVxzY

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I'm sorry, I added examples.

Comment: Not sure you're going to get what you want without a bit of work. This type of animation relies on `strokeDasharray` so when you animate the line drawing it removes whatever dashes you have set, there is an article about doing exactly what you're looking for using D3js here https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/01/animating-dashed-line-d3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate a dashed line, there's a cheat way, which is to animate a line that's on top of it, as you say.

The better way, though slightly more complicated, is to use a mask.  You mask the dasked line with a matching line, and then animate the path that's in the mask.

**Demo**

```js
anime({
  targets: '#mask-path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 3000,
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, linen, aqua);
}

div {
  width: 900px;
  height: 228px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 900 228' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <defs>
      <mask id="anim-mask">
        <path id="mask-path"
              d="M20 0 L 880 0 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20 L 900 208 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, 20 L 20 228 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, -20 L 0 15"
              fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path d="M20 0 L 880 0 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20 L 900 208 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, 20 L 20 228 a 20, 20, 0, 0, 1, -20, -20 L 0 15"
          fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.6" stroke-dasharray="5" mask="url(#anim-mask)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this method works great for curved lines, but if I try to use different path (like a line) `d="M 8 24 V 129.90769841120795"` the mask doesn't work, can you tell me why? I have added examples of working and non-working paths in the codepen https://codepen.io/n4ks/pen/ExmVxzY

Comment: When a path is just a vertical line like that, It's width is officially 0.  The size of the mask image that is generated is, by default, based on the width and height of the shape it is applied to (see `maskUnits="objectBoundingBox"`).  This is great for most shapes, but not this one. In this case, the mask image width will also be 0. Which will result in no mask.  The fix is that you have to specify the bounds of the mask yourself.  Change it to: `<mask id="anim-mask2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="6" y="24" width="4" height="106">`.